# Creating nodes for linked list in a while loop in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create nodes for a linked list in a while loop. The code works, but it is not very pretty. How would I get the same results the proper way?

```
root = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // Allocates memory for first node
pointer = root; // Set pointer to first node
char buf[MAXBUF]; // Buffer for each line

int size = 1; // Counts nodes.

/* Write to list */
while(fgets(buf, MAXBUF, f) != NULL) // Puts each line in a node through buffer
{
    strncpy(pointer->data, buf, MAXBUF); // Puts line in character array in node
    pointer->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // Allocates memory for new node
    size++; // Increments for each node. Root is 1, so first round in loop is 2
    pointer = pointer->next; // Sets pointer to next node
}
size--; // Removes 1 count for last node
free(pointer); // Frees last allocated node
pointer = NULL;
```

Comment: Enclose your memory allocation argument in a function inside your structure and make it look like a constructor of your node "object". Depending on how you would like to use your ll, you may implement push, pop, enqueue, deque, size, etc. functions like those of standard data structures

Comment: @AlfredHuang in C you can't have "a function inside your structure" (except as pointers, which you'd need to initialize, and would take up space for every node), if that's what you mean. If you mean something else, you might want to clarify your comment.

Comment: Any particular reason why you leave `root` as a dangling pointer, if `fgets` doesn't give any lines?

Comment: Elaborating on @AlfredHuang's suggestion: You can do "poor man's object orientation" by making your struct opaqe to users. A public header file would not reveal the struct members, just operations on pointers (implying that all structs must be on the heap). A factory function would malloc and initialize a struct. Another function would append it to another struct.-- Aside from OO I am not too happy with the pre-allocation you perform which makes a finalizing free() necessary: I would allocate only when neded, inside the loop.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy`. You've already prevented overflowing the array by passing its size to `fgets`. Further, while `strncpy` won't overflow the array, it will corrupt your string if the input is too long, and future code will not work right. Read **carefully** about what it does. Then file it away as one of the functions that you're not going to use.

Comment: @Pete Becker Agree with `strcpy()` concerns expect with this usage.  `strncpy(pointer->data, buf, MAXBUF);`, `pointer->data` will always be `'\0'` terminated as `strlen(buf) < MAXBUF`.

Comment: @chux - you're right that `strncpy` won't corrupt data **in this case**; it merely adds unnecessary overhead. `strncpy` is a **very** specialized function; it is almost never appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The technique you're trying to accomplish in building your ordered linked list is called *forward-chaining*. A pointer-to-pointer makes the task trivial for building a simple linked list while retaining its input order. Error checking memory allocations not-withstanding, it is done something like this:

```
struct node *root = NULL, **pp = &root;
char buf[MAXBUF] = {0};
size_t size = 0;

while (fgets(buf, MAXBUF, f) != NULL)
{
    *pp = calloc(1, sizeof(**pp));
    strncpy((*pp)->data, buf, MAXBUF-1);
    pp = &(*pp)->next;
    ++size;
}
*pp = NULL; // terminate the last node
```

---

**How It Works**

The parts of this that mandate further elaboration follow this general algorithm:

1. Utilize a pointer-to-pointer to always hold the address of the pointer that will be populated with the address of the next node to add. The initial value of this pointer-to-pointer is the address of the `root` pointer: `&root`.
2. Acquire a new node, storing its address in `*pp`, where `pp` is the pointer-to-pointer from (1)
3. Once the node is finished being configured, change the address stored in `pp` to be the address of the `next` member pointer held within the node just added. This step sets up the target location where the *next* node will be added if needed.
4. When finished processing input, the last-node-added's `next` member pointer has its address currently held in `pp`. If no nodes were added to the list, then `pp` still holds the address of `root`. To terminate the list, this pointer must be set to NULL.

So on to the code:

```
struct node *root = NULL, **pp = &root
```

The above line declares the root pointer, initialized to NULL (optional, but I hate indeterminate pointers *anywhere* in-code), and a pointer-to-pointer that holds the address of `root`. From there...

```
*pp = malloc(sizeof(**pp));
```

This allocates a new node, storing its address at whatever pointer is currently being addressed by the pointer-to-pointer `pp`. On the initial pass that pointer is the `root` pointer. On subsequent passes it will always hold the address of the `next member within the last-node-added on a prior iteration.  But it *always* holds the address of pointer that is to receive the next new node.

After the current node is finished being configured copy, then this is done:

```
pp = &(*pp)->next;
```

This stores the address of the just-added-node's `next` member in the pointer-to-pointer. When we loop around for the next iteration, this is where we will hang the next new node. Finally, after the loop finishes, this is done:

```
*pp = NULL;
```

This sets the pointer pointed-to by `pp` to NULL. Now think about what pointer that is:

- If no items were populated in the list, then `pp` still holds the address of `root` and this will reestablish `root` as NULL; exactly what you want if the list is empty.
- If any nodes were read, then `pp` will hold the address of the *last* added-node's `next` pointer, which should set to NULL to terminate the linked list. Again, exactly what this code does.

---

**Addendum: Printing the list**

Per request, printing the list after this is simply:

```
struct node *ptr = root;
while (ptr)
{
    printf("data: %s\n", ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

For C99 and later,

```
for (struct node *ptr = root; ptr; ptr = ptr->next)
    printf("data: %s\n", ptr->data);
```

Comment: @PeterSchneider you may want to look at this again. This builds the list from conception, not amending to an existing list. Overwriting `root` on the initial pass is *precisely* what it is supposed to do (that's where the first node must be hung). The pointer-to-pointer is what makes this algorithm so elegant, and if you aren't familiar with them it may look a little odd.

Comment: I see -- root keeps pointing to the start of the list. My apologies.

Comment: @PeterSchneider correct. All writes are through `pp`, which initially holds `&root`. The only time it changes is on the *initial* add. The var `pp` always holds the address of the pointer that will receive the *next* new node. On the first iteration, that pointer is.. `root`.

Comment: +1 Nice Answer. There is only one thing I don't like about the code: `strncpy(pointer->data, buf, MAXBUF);`. I think that the allocation of the node should be done in a better way - depending on the size of the line. That big buffer in every node is ugly.

Comment: @firda This question was originally on StackOverflow, not here. Otherwise I would likely have provided a much more appropriate answer, just fyi. It was migrated later. Looks like I'll have to make it respectable rather than conceptual.

Comment: @WhozCraig: It was migrated including your answer? Maybe, this should be marked somehow.

Comment: @firda yeah, it included the answer. First time I've ever seen that done before. usually the question is simply replicated, but remains on SO. I was surprised myself.

Comment: @firda - all, I can explain the [process in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor), if you are interested. Also your answer is OK for Code Review (perhaps not brilliant, but it gets my +1). Happy to chat about that too.

Answer (score 2):

### Memory management

You have a memory management bug due to pointer aliasing.

> ```
> root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
> pointer = root;
> char buf[MAXBUF];
>
> int size = 1; // Counts nodes.
> ```

So far, we have

$$
\newcommand{rptr}[1]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{lptr}[1]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\longleftarrow}}
\mathtt{root} \rptr{}\ \fbox{struct node} \lptr{} \mathtt{pointer} \\
\mathtt{size} = 1
$$

Suppose that there is no input at all.  That means that we'll skip the `while` loop, and proceed with

> ```
> size--;
> free(pointer);
> pointer = NULL;
> ```

Then we end up with

$$
\newcommand{rptr}[1]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\longrightarrow}}
\mathtt{root} \rptr{}\ \textit{freed memory} \qquad
\mathtt{pointer} \rptr{}\ \textit{NULL} \\
\mathrm{size} = 0
$$

One would expect the result to be equivalent to `root = NULL`.  The best remedy is to allocate the node when it is actually needed, as written by @WhozCraig.

### Style

Writing every statement twice — once in code, and again in a comment — is tedious.  The comments don't provide insight.  If anything, they become a maintenance liability.

Rather, you should write your code to be more self-explanatory.  For example, naming  your pointers `head` and `tail` would be a huge hint as to their purpose.  In contrast, naming your pointer `pointer` is redundant and unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

1. Rather than print to `buf` and then copy to `pointer->data`, skip the middle-man

   ```
   while(fgets(pointer->data, sizeof pointer->data, f) != NULL)
   ```
2. Rather than start count at 1, start at 0 and skip the final decrement.

   ```
   int size = 0;
   while (...) {
     ...
     size++;
   }
   // size--;
   ```
3. Simplify `malloc()` usage, IMO this style easier to maintain and less error prone.

   ```
   // root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   // pointer->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   root = malloc(sizeof *root);
   pointer->next = malloc(sizeof *(pointer->next));
   ```
4. IMO, initializing the complete structure promptly after memory allocation is a good thing.  (Also with `root`)

   ```
   pointer->next = malloc(sizeof *(pointer->next));
   pointer = pointer->next;
   pointer->next = NULL;
   pointer->data[0] = '\0';
   pointer->other_fields = 0;

   // or

   pointer->next = calloc(1, sizeof *(pointer->next));
   ```
5. Checking if `malloc()` returned `NULL` is good also.
6. Like the setting the pointer to `NULL` after `free()`.   A good compiler will optimize out if it can, but good to scrub pointers when done.

   ```
   free(pointer);
   pointer = NULL;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

My normal approach would be to encapsulate the linked list and provide functions to create a list, add a node, remove a node, etc.  So your example comes down to:

```
List *list = list_create(...);
if (!list) {
    // handle error and exit
}
char buf[MAXBUF];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f) != NULL) {
    if (list_add(list, buf) < 0) {
        // handle error and exit
    }
}
```